# Enable LdapEnforceChannelBinding in Java based applications

Tags: java, ldap, kerberos, gssapi

Microsoft introduced a 'LdapEnforceChannelBinding' option requiring clients to provide channel binding information in order to connect to AD over SSL/TLS. After this has enabled in AD, Java applications which use Kerberos/ LDAP authentication receive following error from the server.

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090346: LdapErr: DSID-0C09056D, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 80090346, v2580
```

My code uses LoginContext to authenticate and DirContext with GSSAPI security mechanism.

Is there a way to enable channel binding in Java code to fix this issue?

Comment: You don't need TLS when you use Kerberos. Simply require `qop=auth-conf`.

Comment: Please follow: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2019-December/021052.html

Comment: We tried above options but they are not working.
Using qop=auth-conf with LDAP connection is fine & it provides integrity & privacy protection. But we are using LDAPS. With LDAPS if you enable ldap channel binding(value=2), then we are getting above error.
Is there any JAVA Library/API that supports "LDAP Channel Binding"?

Comment: @Michael-O, what if we want to use ldaps with kerberos?

Comment: @jasmin9891 Technically, I see no benefit if you use AES256.

Comment: @pasabsb have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with OpenJDK and is supposedly implemented in JDK 16 which is in early access but is planned to be backported to JDK 8, though I haven't gotten it to work yet.

Here is the bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8245527

See my issue here for more details. [LDAPS Channel Binding with GSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64392108/ldaps-channel-binding-with-gss)