# Connecting to LDAPS with GSS and Channel Binding

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, gssapi, java-16

I'm trying to bind to an Active Directory server with GSS on a Windows computer that is logged in as a domain user. Normally, this works fine. But when signing and binding is being enforced

(see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520412/2020-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-for-windows)

GSS fails to bind. According to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8245527, this feature was added in JDK 16 (b18), but I have been unable to successfully bind failing with the error message

`javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090346: LdapErr: DSID-0C090595, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 80090346, v3839`

Other relevant details:

- My company has 3 domain controllers and each returns the same error.
  They are currently set to value=1 (when supported), though value=2
  (always) has the same effect.
- I'm fairly certain that my project is using JDK 16 build 20.
- When binding with a username and password, all works as expected.
- Additionally, binding via LDAP (not LDAPS) works with GSS.
- The critical combination is GSS + LDAPS.

**EDIT**
I get the same behavior in JDK 15.0.1.9 as I do in JDK 16. This makes me think  that the functionality is not implemented fully in JDK16b20 *however* after inspecting the included source code I can see where the code was added.

Below is the code being used to connect to the server:

```
public class ActiveDirectory {

    public LdapContext getConnection(boolean ssl) throws NamingException {
        return getConnection(null, null, ssl);
    }
    public LdapContext getConnection(String username, String password, boolean ssl) throws NamingException {
        String domainName = "";
        try {
            String fqdn = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName(); //lookup the domain
            if (fqdn.split("\\.").length > 1) {
                domainName = fqdn.substring(fqdn.indexOf(".") + 1);
            }
        } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
        }
        Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
        if (password != null) { 
            password = password.trim();
            if (password.length() == 0) { //the password was blank. Bind with GSS anyway
                password = null;
            }
        }
        if (password != null) { // a password was provided. Bind as that user
            String principalName = username + "@" + domainName;
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principalName);
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        } else { //no password. Bind with GSS
            String principalName = System.getProperty("user.name")  + "@" + domainName;
            username=System.getProperty("user.name");
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principalName);
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "GSSAPI");
            System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.native", "true");
        }
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        String ldapURL = "";
        for (String server : domainControllers) {
            if (ssl) { //use SSL to bind
                ldapURL = "ldaps://" + server + "." + domainName + "/";
                props.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
                props.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.tls.cbtype", "tls-server-end-point"); //use channel binding !!! DOESNT WORK WITH GSS. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8245527?attachmentViewMode=gallery
                props.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "2000");
            } else { //dont use ssl to bind
                ldapURL = "ldap://" + server + "." + domainName + '/';
                props.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "");
            }
            props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,ldapURL);
            try {
                return connect(props);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        throw new NamingException("Failed to authenticate " + username + "@" + domainName);
    }

    private LdapContext connect(Hashtable props) throws NamingException {
        return new InitialLdapContext(props, null);
    }
```

If anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have no clue about LDAP, so I'm just guessing, but I've noticed that [JDK-8245527](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8245527) mentions some registry entries (see "How to reproduce", step 2). Did you do that?

Comment: @NicolaiParlog The registry entries mentioned are how to configure windows server to enforce signing and binding. They have nothing to do with client-side.